# Rails select list reverts to top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, select

I have number of select lists in my rails application like this:

```
<li>Company<span><%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]} %></span></li>
```

They all work well, except - sometimes if you go to the edit view, the select list reverts to the top item, not the item that was chosen when creating. So if you go to an edit view and then click update without actually making any changes, the lists default to the top item - even though you didn't touch them.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks,

Danny

EDIT:

```
<% form_for (@kase), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|  %>


<li>Appointed Surveyor<span><%= f.select :appointedsurveyor_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {:selected => @kase.appointedsurveyor_id}  %></span></li>
    <li>Surveyor Name<span><%= f.select :surveyorperson_id, Person.all.collect { |x| [x.personname, x.id]}, {:selected => @kase.surveyorperson_id} %></span></li>
```

I have tried the above, but sadly it still seems to revert to the default value.

I'm stuck on this, I can't find any tutorials etc on this at all.

**EDIT 2:**

```
<li>Appointed Surveyor<span><%= f.select :appointedsurveyor_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.appointedsurveyor_id rescue "")} %></span></li>
    <li>Surveyor Name<span><%= f.select :surveyorperson_id, Person.all.collect { |x| [x.personname, x.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.surveyorperson_id rescue "")} %></span></li>
```

Comment: please post: 1. The code that generates the form ('form_for..') and 2. the code that instantiates the company (in the controller)

Comment: are you sure `@kase.appointedsurveyor_id` and `@kase.surveyorperson_id` are not blank?

Comment: Positive, but should I use the same code (the one above) for the new and edit views? Or just the edit?

Comment: To use in both `new` and `edit` you may need a `rescue`: `:selected => (@kase.appointedsurveyor_id rescue "")`

Comment: Sorry, could you put the above into context? I'm really confused.

<li>Company<span><%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {rescue: :selected => (@kase.appointedsurveyor_id rescue "") %></span></li>

Is that right?

Comment: No. `<li>Company<span><%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.appointedsurveyor_id rescue "") %></span></li>`

Comment: Updated question above, it seems to work for the first instance (appointed surveyor) but not the second (surveyorperson).

Comment: What is working? The `selected` option is right now? If it's not working for the surveyor name, then `@kase.surveyorperson_id` is empty.

Comment: The simplest way is to show you: http://screenr.com/Fcp

Comment: It turns out I had the fields in the database as strings not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the fields in the database as strings not integers.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to make sure of it with the third parameter, try the following code:

```
<li>Company<span><%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {:selected => @your_instance_name.company_id} %></span></li>
```

Make sure that you replace `@your_instance_name` with the instance variable you use at the form_for tag.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but it didnt seem to work. I have pasted the code I tried in my question in case I made a mistake.